# What is the number after "GOTO" in Java bytecode?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, goto

[image]

Java version: 1.8.0_73-b02 64bit

Why command `GOTO 10`'s bytecode is `A7 FF F7`?
Is `A7` corresponds to `goto`, and `FF F7` corresponds to `10`?

Why `A7 FF F7` is `GOTO 10`?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.goto)?

Comment: `0xFFF7` corresponds to `-10`, not `10`.

Comment: @Kayaman oh! Is that a bug of the class viewer?

Comment: Well I don't know that. It could be a bug in your eyes for all I know.

Comment: @Kayaman: actually, `FFF7` corresponds to `-9` and the viewer correctly displays `10`, because it converted the relative position to an absolute position, `19 -9 == 10`. That's easier to recognize by looking at the next `goto` at position `25`. It's `A7 FF E9`, having offset `-23` and being displayed as `2`, as `25 -23  == 2`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two bytes identify the memory address of the next intended instruction. Take a look at the description for GOTO in this [bytecode listing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings):

> goes to another instruction at branchoffset (signed short constructed from unsigned bytes branchbyte1 << 8 + branchbyte2)

Or, see here in the [official javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.goto)

> The unsigned bytes branchbyte1 and branchbyte2 are used to construct a signed 16-bit branchoffset, where branchoffset is (branchbyte1 << 8) | branchbyte2. Execution proceeds at that offset from the address of the opcode of this goto instruction. The target address must be that of an opcode of an instruction within the method that contains this goto instruction.